# Issue with VSCode c++ compiling

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to initialize a map with the brackets in c++, like this:

```
    const unordered_map <int, int> prova = 
    {
        {0,1},
        {4,2}
    };
```

If I compile on VSCode I keep getting the `error: non-aggregate type 'const unordered_map<int, int>' cannot be initialized with an initializer list`.

I included `-std=c++20` in the compiler arguments configuration field and tried every combination of g++/clang/clang++/gcc etc. getting the same result.

When I compile from the terminal instead, with `g++ -std=c++20 -o prova prova.cpp` everything works fine unless I omit the argument `-std=c++20`, in which case I get the same error as above.

I have to admit my knowledge about c++ is very limited. As far as I know, my system is up to date. Full output of `g++ —-version` is the following

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0 Thread model: posix InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

The `.vscode/settings.json` file is empty, while `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++20",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-x64",
            "compilerArgs": [
                "-std=c++20"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

and this is `.vscode/tasks.json`:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ compila il file attivo",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-fcolor-diagnostics",
                "-fansi-escape-codes",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Attività generata dal debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Any idea on what may be causing this issue and how to solve it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Sorry, but I'm [not getting any errors](https://ideone.com/WK8EZY) with g++.

Comment: What version of g++ did you use when compiling from terminal?

Comment: Hi @KarenBaghdasaryan, g++ version is 4.2.1

Comment: versions below 4.8 didn't have even full C++11

Comment: If you use g++ version 4.2.1, then I am even surprised it didn't complain about, `-std=c++20` parameter. The version you mentioned probably uses `c++98` standard by default, so the feature you are trying to use in not implemented prior to `c++11` standard

Comment: What does your `settings.json` file look like?

Comment: @KarenBaghdasaryan If you are referring to the `settings.json` file located in the `.vscode` directory, it appears to be empty.

Comment: Adding `"-std=c++20"` to `"args"` in `tasks.json` should do the trick, the same if you compile from the terminal. BTW, given the full output of `--version`, you should have `clang 13.0` installed.

Comment: @Bob__ Adding `"-std=c++20"` to `"args"` did the trick indeed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `"-std=c++20"` to `"args"` in `tasks.json` solved the issue.